# Ruby Datamapper .count always returns 0

Tags: ruby, postgresql, datamapper

Whenever I try and count the returned records from datamapper it always returns as 0, whether there is a user or not.

```
User.count(:username=>params[:username])

class User
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,  Serial
  property :username,  String, unique_index: true, required: true, length: 3..32
  property :password,  String, required: true, length: 5..64
  property :email,  String, unique_index: true, required: true, format: :email_address

end
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that there's a user in your database?  Is there more context to your code snippet that you can provide?

Comment: @Makoto There is definitely a user there, because if I remove the if statement then all the other code is executed fine which involves getting details from the database. As for more code, I've just updated it with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try `User.all(:username=>params[:username])` in console
and then try

`User.count(:username=>params[:username])` for that ENV